# Am I on the right track to figure out this combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Say, we have 4 red balls, 4 blue balls, 4 green balls, 4 yellow balls. How many ways are there to form a sequence of 10 balls such that every color of ball occurs at least twice?

My thought:
r = red b = blue g = green y = yellow * = undetermined

Every arrangments should in this form: rrbbggyy**

Case 1: two * are same

$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1}10!}{4!2!2!2!}$

Case 2: two * are different

$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}10!}{3!3!2!2!}$

Result = Case 1 + Case 2

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You mean every color occurs at least twice? Also, are balls of the same color considered to be distinguishable?

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid My bad. Every color. Has changed.

Comment: Thanks. So if you have a sequence of balls and you interchange two balls that have the same color, is the result considered to be a different sequence?

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid It should be considered as one case.

Comment: @Isham I don't know. But my thinking is to choose 1 color from 4 colors. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Isham That's what I initially thought. But, for example, the number of arrangements of sequence rrbbggyyrr is $\frac{10!}{4!2!2!2!}$. and the arrangements of sequence rrbbggyyry is $\frac{10!}{3!3!2!2!}$. They are different cases. So if you use $\binom{8}{2}$, it cannot distinguish the above cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's two cases.

First. We have one quadruplet of 4 balls of the same color. There are 4 variations here to form quadruplets. The rest 6 balls will automatically form 3 doublets (to satisfy the conditions of the problem). The overall number of placing them into a sequence is permutations with repetition:
$$\frac{10!}{4!\,2!\,2!\,2!}$$
But we have to multiply it by 4 because we have 4 variations. So it is 
$$4\cdot\frac{10!}{4!\,2!\,2!\,2!}$$

Second case. We have two triplets and two doublets. How many variations in terms of triplets and doublets? The answer is four choose two -- that is combinations.
The rest is the same as above:
$${4\choose2}\cdot\frac{10!}{3!\,3!\,2!\,2!}$$

And finally the overall number of possible strings of balls:
$$4\cdot\frac{10!}{4!\,2!\,2!\,2!}+{4\choose2}\cdot\frac{10!}{3!\,3!\,2!\,2!}$$

Comment: "The rest 6 balls will automatically form 3 doublets". Do we need to consider how to choose the color from one doublet? For example, rrb1b2yyggyy and rrb3b4yyggyy. I thought this should be different so I use $\binom{4}{2}$

Comment: @Andy It's already defined by a quadruplet. And all balls of the same color are indistinguishable here. Then we just 'permutate' everything.

Comment: @Andy In other words there are only $4$ ways to form one quadruplet and three doublets before ‘starting permutations’ to form all kinds of strings.

Answer (score 1):

The partition by distinct colors can be either $10=4+2+2+2$ or $10=3+3+2+2$. In the first case, you also need to choose the $1$ color that is to be used 4 times, and in the second case, the $2$ colors that are to be used $3$ times. Thus, the total number of choices is
$$
\binom{4}{1}\binom{10}{4,2,2,2}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{10}{3,3,2,2}
$$